# ImageView in UITableViewCell with tag propety

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I added an ImageView through the storyboard and I am trying to set it programmatically with the tag property.

```
UIImageView * imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage"];
```

The reason I thought this would work is because using the same method for a UILabel worked.

```
 UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
 label.text =  @"some text";
```

Comment: Did you check whether the `imageView` is actually `!= nil`?

Comment: I can for example add a background color but when I try to set the .image property and then NSLog the imageView.image, I get null.

Comment: Maybe `[UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage"]` is `nil`.